# How to fix app display issue in different screen?

Tags: java, android, xml

Why my app display is varying from device to device

[This is output I,m getting in some devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E28Kg.jpg)

[This is output from some devices, where you can clearly see the right side is cutting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfSD8.jpg)

Please help me to get my app UI fixed from every side in different devices like the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E28Kg.jpg).

My XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_pic"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/close_btn" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="135dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/timer"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="15s"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#3B3B3B"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="97dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Score: 430"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add code of xml @Laxminarayan Das

Comment: I have added xml code @yuvrajsinh

Comment: start using layout_weight with weightSum in these types of cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can fix your view with only RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_round_close" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/timer"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="15s"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#3B3B3B"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Score: 430"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can achive this as below by using `weightSum` as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/close_btn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".4"
        android:background="@drawable/timer"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="15s"
        android:textColor="#3B3B3B"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Score: 430"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: same result, the right side is still cutting @yuvrajsinh

Comment: replaced this full xml with yours?

Comment: please check it is working perfact in my both screens @LaxminarayanDas